# Sending intents from service to activity only when activity is running

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ipc

I have a service and application. There is communication between them by sending intents on specific situations. In activity I register and unregister broadcast receiver to collect this intents. Intents from service are sending when particular callback method is executed. Is there a possibility to send this intents only when activity is in the foreground? Because when this is hide there is no need to gather this intents (it helpful only to show some situations in real time)? I figure out that in activity could be static field that indicates about such situation, but I don't know how to get access to activity from service and additionally I found information that this is vary bad design practise.. Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: Is your service (supposed to be) running all the time?

Comment: Yes service running all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this in your `Activity`:

```
public static boolean isRunning;
```

Then in your `onPause` to set `isRunning = false;`

and in `onResume` set it to `isRunning = true;`

Then from your `Service` you can simply call `ActivityName.isRunning` to know if it is in foreground or not!

Comment: "I figure out that in activity could be static field that indicates about such situation.." I have service and app in different projects and this is more difficult to access each other classes and additionally and asked how to avoid creating dependency in code between them if it possible.

Comment: They are in different projects, but that does not matter. Just use the whole path "packagename.class.isRunning" to get the same result.

Comment: Ok I understand but it forces me to add to service's build path, path to application project and in my situation I already have dependency of app to service. Eclipse shows errors with circular dependency, I manage with that to change displaying that message like warning not error.. Is it possible to manage with this on different approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a static variable within the activity.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
     static boolean active = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         active = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         active = false;
      }
}
```

Add just check in service as

```
if(MyActivity.active)
{
//send broadcast.
}
```

OR
go with this to check status of activity is it active or not

```
public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
            if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
                return true;                                  
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: "I figure out that in activity could be static field that indicates about such situation.." I have service and app in different projects and this is more difficult to access each other classes and additionally and asked how to avoid creating dependency in code between them if it possible.

Comment: or you can check activity in specified app using it's package name as well like (packagename.activityClass.active)

Comment: Please see my answer to Carnal comment, answers are identical :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a local boolean variable in service:

```
protected boolean mIsAppRunning;
```

Call `startService()` with true/false extra when app resumes/stops:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent service = new Intent("my.service.ACTION");
    service.putExtra("IS_MY_ACTIVITY_RUNNING", true);
    startService(service);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent service = new Intent("my.service.ACTION");
    service.putExtra("IS_MY_ACTIVITY_RUNNING", false);
    startService(service);
}
```

Check that extra in service's `onStartCommand()` and assign its value to `mIsAppRunning`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        mIsAppRunning = intent.getBooleanExtra("IS_MY_ACTIVITY_RUNNING", false);
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If you design the logic in the service a little carefully, you may even get rid of the local variable, `mIsAppRunning`, and call the required methods depending on the intent extra value.

Hope this helps.